# Magento - Confirmation Link E-Mail Startpage not Customer account

Tags: php, magento, redirect, confirmation

How can I edit the confirmation link redirect?

```
 {{store url="customer/account/confirm/" _query_id=$customer.id _query_key=$customer.confirmation _query_back_url=$back_url}}
```

Now I am redirected to the customer account. I tried to edit the url, but then my user is not confirmed.

Is there a possibility to include a redirect in the *customer/account/confirm/* ?

Daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure, but it seems to me that you have to pass $back_url to create a redirect where you want after confirmation of your account.
If you somehow edit or remove the link to confirm, then your account wouldn't be confirmed (logically), so if you want to redirect a user somewhere else, you have to change another parameter.

Comment: Mmh. that´s true. I searched for another parameter but did not find any which let me customize the redirect. (sadly)

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve? Am I right, that you want to redirect a user somewhere after his account is confirmed?

Comment: With my confirmation link in the e-mail I don´t want that the user is linked to his account, instead he should be redirected to the startpage of the shop. Normally he is redirected to /customer/account/ I just want to get the base url.

Comment: The back_url is intended for this behaviour, if I'm not mistaken - confirm account and redirect to $back_url. Also, as far as I know, if you activate in admin area flag in admin area (path in admin: configuration->advanced->admin->startup page section and change it from dashboard to something else. Maybe, that will help.
Sorry, was interrupted: In case you change this setting any logged in user after login (or registration as well) would be redirected to the page you set in this setting. Should work for you, if I got it right.

Comment: This was it. I just included the url plain where $back_url was set. This worked. Now I have to figure out how to set the baseurl in a template. Thank you very much!!!!

Comment: Glad to help!
Should be smth similar to {base_url} .
Please, accept the answer to the question, so it would show that the question is answered.)